# material-ui <SelectField> Items are not showing in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

material-ui  Items are not showing. I want to show categories of products in SelectField but its not working.
whwn I click on selectfield it does not show any item
All code of my component is given below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

const style = {
    padding: '10px',
    textAlign: 'center'
};

const categories = ["mobile","laptop","camera"];

class AddProduct extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            productName: '',
            productCategory: '',
        }
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
        this.inputHandler = this.inputHandler.bind(this);
    }

    inputHandler(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

handleChangeCategory = (event, index, value) => {this.setState({productCategory:value}); console.log("value", value)}

    render() {
        return (
            <div ><center>
                <h1>Add Product for Auction</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.submit} >
                    <br />
                    <br />
                   <SelectField
          floatingLabelText="Catogory"
          value={this.state.productCategory}
          onChange={this.handleChangeCategory}
        >
          <MenuItem value={"mobile"} primaryText="Mobile" />
          <MenuItem value={"laptop"} primaryText="Laptop" />
          <MenuItem value={"camera"} primaryText="Camera" />
        </SelectField><br />
                    <br />

                    <TextField
                        type="text"
                        hintText="Product Title"
                        name="productName"
                        value={this.state.productName}
                        floatingLabelText="Product Title"
                        onChange={this.inputHandler}
                    />
                    <RaisedButton type="submit" label="Add Product" primary={false} secondary={true} /> <br /><br />
                </form>
            </center>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddProduct;
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined the function **submit** and according to your code you are trying to bind it.

```
this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
```

define the function submit

```
   submit(){
    // do something
      }
```

And try to use **ES6 fat arrow functions** so you dont have to bind each and every function, like you have done in the above code.

Try something like this (using ES6 fat arrows)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

const style = {
    padding: '10px',
    textAlign: 'center'
};

const categories = ["mobile","laptop","camera"];

class AddProduct extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            productName: '',
            productCategory: '',
        }

    }

    submit =()=>{

    }

    inputHandler =(e)=> {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

handleChangeCategory = (event, index, value) => {this.setState({productCategory:value}); console.log("value", value)}

    render() {
        return (
            <div ><center>
                <h1>Add Product for Auction</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.submit} >
                    <br />
                    <br />
                   <SelectField
          floatingLabelText="Catogory"
          value={this.state.productCategory}
          onChange={this.handleChangeCategory}
        >
          <MenuItem value={"mobile"} primaryText="Mobile" />
          <MenuItem value={"laptop"} primaryText="Laptop" />
          <MenuItem value={"camera"} primaryText="Camera" />
        </SelectField><br />
                    <br />

                    <TextField
                        type="text"
                        hintText="Product Title"
                        name="productName"
                        value={this.state.productName}
                        floatingLabelText="Product Title"
                        onChange={this.inputHandler}
                    />
                    <RaisedButton type="submit" label="Add Product" primary={false} secondary={true} /> <br /><br />
                </form>
            </center>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddProduct;
```

Comment: @NaveedAheer hmm that's odd. Can you put the whole code of that component?

Comment: unfortunately items are not loaded in <selectfield> and thanks @TRomesh for your answer

Comment: @NaveedAheer did you try the whole code that ive given? try to clear cache on your browser. Ive checked the code it must work.